# Nesting XML namespaces with a default

Tags: xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

What is the proper way to nest XML names spaces?

Must I do :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<top xmlns="http://url1" xmlns:b="http://url2">
    <b:second>
    </b:second>
</top>
```

or is the following ok

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<top xmlns="http://url1">
    <b:second xmlns:b="http://url2">
    </b:second>
</top>
```

Also, is it ok to set the second level to be the default? For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:top xmlns:a="http://url1">
    <second xmlns="http://url2">
    </second>
</a:top>
```

should the second level be declared as being in the first levels namespace?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:top xmlns:a="http://url1">
    <a:second xmlns="http://url2">
        <third>text</third>
    </a:second>
</a:top>
```

Comment: All of these forms are OK in the sense that it all qualify as *well-formed* XML. Which one to choose seems to be subjective, just like a question whether to name the outer-most element `top` or `root` in your samples...

Answer (score 0):

All of these are "OK" as long as the namespace inheritance rules are giving you the result you intend.

A good way to check would be to pass it through a parser that tells you what namespace each element is in. There are *many* ways to skin that cat. Here is a simple java program:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;

public class Parse
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(new File(args[0]), new Handler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class Handler extends DefaultHandler
    {
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("qName="+qName+" uri="+uri);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using linux, the following is a slightly more verbose equivalent:

```
xmllint --sax file.xml
```